# como puedo mostrar un mesaje, si el usuario ingresa mal el formato de fecha?

Tags: java, java-8

hola me surge que quiero mostrar un mensaje para el usario
usando este metodo. alguien que me ayude?
pero me muestra la fecha actual que esta bien . pero al ingresar otro formato de fecha no me muestra la ventana que le pido "debe ingresar formato valido" . mi campo es textoFecha

```
     private void cargarFechaVenta() {

   
        Calendar miCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
       
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        txtFecha.setText(String.valueOf(dateFormat.format(miCalendar.getTime())));
        
        try {
            java.util.Date Fecha = dateFormat.parse(txtFecha.getText());
} catch (ParseException pe) {
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null , "Debe ingresar formato valido.", "yyy-MM-dd", 
JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE );
}
            
        
   
     }
```

Comment: probaste agregando un if a la variable dateFormat ! dateFormat ? por ejemplo: si la variable ingresada es distinta de dateFormat imprimier error...

Comment: como deberia quedar me darias un ejemplo? el problema es que me muestra el mensaje cuando inicioo el programa y no cuando inserto la fecha me acabo de dar cuenta tambien.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que aquí no estás verificando nada, simplemente le muestras el formato de la fecha al usuario usando la fecha actual, y luego incondicionalmente muestras el mensaje de error.

Tendrías que hacer algo así:

```
try {
  Date fecha = dateFormat.parse(txtFecha.getText());
} catch (ParseException pe) {
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null , "Debe ingresar formato valido.", "yyy-MM-dd", 
JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE );
}
```

Comment: hola gracias si intente pero no me muestra la ventana y me tira un error !

Comment: Y qué error? Esa parte del código que puse, es a modo de ejemplo, no sé cómo es tu aplicación, pero básicamente es para ponerlo luego que el usuario ingresa la fecha, quizá en el evento lostfocus (o algo así, no conozco mucho de Swing)